# HTAccess redirect of base folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

just a sense check. 
I have

domain.com/username which I want to redirect to a PHP query string, Im doing this using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /profile/display.php?id=$1&function=$2 [L]
```

However, I would also like to have folders, like domain.com/about that are not redirected. 
How can I achieve that? Is that even possible, or does the regex over ride everything from the start?

Comment: Apologies, this is the redirect regex Im currently uing:

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /profile/display.php?id=$1&function=$2 [L]
```

Without redirection for real directory or real file.

Comment: Thats great. Just a further question, if I wanted to enable functions like domain.com/hello and domain.com/hello/  (no .html page name), to result in display.php?id=$1 whats the best way to do this?

Comment: This is a new and another question. There are many examples on this site.

Comment: I cant ask another question, because I have to wait three days.

Comment: Ive managed to get the following working, however its stopped finding files and directories that exist:

Comment: `code Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/|)$ /profile/display.php?id=$1&function=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /profile/display.php?id=$1&function=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|)$ /profile/display.php?id=$1 [L] `